# How do you set a selected time from a data picker, then show a table with time outputs based on the user selected time?

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, datepicker, var

Basically what I want to do is this...

I have a data picker and go button underneath it. I restricted the date picker to only have time.

I want it so that if the user clicks go, its set the date to a variable named "userSelectedDate". Then a screen shows up next that shows a set of 6 times each with a difference of 1 hr 30 min. So it if the time is 8:00 A.M. then it would result with 6 times: 10:45 P.M./12:15 P.M./1:45 P.M./3:15 P.M./4:45 P.M./6:15 P.M. How do I set the date picker to a variable after the user clicks go, so that I can refer to it in a table view?

Answer (score -1):

What you would need to do is create a new `Date` object using your `userSelectedDate` object and add an 90 minutes to it. The simplest way would be

```
for i in (0 ... 5)
{
     let nextDate = userSelectedDate.addingTimeInterval(90)
     // Add to data model
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: It gives me the error, Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int' and use of unresolved operator '++'; did you mean '+=1'? I don't understand how the first line of code works either, could you explain it? Sorry for my noob questions, just wanna make sure I understand it so I can do it on my own later if needed. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry, I had some typos. It was suppose to be a for loop not a if statement. I changed it in my answer for you to see. Basically in the first line it declares a int equal to 0, next it checks if that int is less than 6. If it is less than 6 it runs the code in the block below it, then it increments `i` up by 1 and checks again. This will run 5 times which I think is what you want.

Comment: How does the compiler know i is representative of the number of times in the date picker? Also, after the edit, it still says consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' insert ';' and expected declaration.

Comment: Is i supposed to be a placeholder for the name/identifier of the datePicker?

Comment: Okay sorry, I've been doing a lot of Objective C work and totally forgot they removed c-style loops from swift like all the way back in Swift 3. I feel like an idiot for not remembering that. I edit it again to show the proper way to loop through code a certain amount of time. From what I understand from your question you need to do add a time to a date object a certain amount of time and that's what this should do. `i` will hold the value of the number 0 through how every amount of times you want it to loop. But you don't need to use that.

Comment: oh I see, but how do I plug this in to the table view and do I put it in the view controller of the first or second screen? Also, it still says expected declaration.

Comment: I don't have any errors in my project might be something you're using inside the loop.
 I don't know how you project is set up but I would implement it right after the user selects the dates and save it in an array. That array I would use to determine how many cells are in the table view cell and the data to populate the cell. But that's kinda outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I'm kinda confused now. How do I write the code for the user selecting a time? Right now all I have is the go button and that is not connected to the date picker. Also I don't want to save it as an array because if a user selects 8:34 for instance than I would have to make seperate code for every odd minute. How do I write the code for add 90 min intervals 6 times to the time they enter?

Comment: From you question it sounded like you already had that set up. Head over to [ray wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/), he has some great tutorials for everything you can think of and will help with that issue. Also head over [here](https://www.weheartswift.com/loops/) and read up on different types of loops in Swift. It's a pretty fundamental part of programming and is something better learned as a whole than told exactly how to do it. My twitter handle is @Seth_Kurk, you can reach me there for some more broad help to keep the comments within scope of the question.